# How to make table view with all section headers floating

Tags: ios, uitableview

So, a client demanded a table view divided in 3 sections and all 3 section headers visible if/when reached the top.

I made a little sketch to describe what I need:
[image]

So, when a user scrolls up, section header one will be floating there, everything normal so far...
The difference I need is when section2 header reaches the top of a table view.

I don't want it to push the section1 header out of the view, but instead I want it to hang in there, just below the Section1 header...
Same goes for Section3  header, I want it to be below Section2 header, which will stay below Section1 header.

I couldn't figure out how to do that by myself, and I  hope somebody has a clue how to do this?

Can I override UITableView class and then disable previous-section-header-pushing-from-the-view behaviour?

If not, can I maybe use UICollectionView with custom layout somehow (I never did use UICollectionView, so I'm asking if anyone with experionce thinks it's possible)